# Returning two variables to two different divs from another php on onClick

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

This is the Index.php file

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="submit.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" id="formsett">

        <div class="col-sm-4"> 
            <div id="div1">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div id="idform">
                <form id="idform" method="POST">
                <p>
                    <label> <b> Enter NIC No: </b> </label> <br/>
                    <input type="text" id="idno" name="idno" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="button" id="btn" onclick="SubmitFormData();" value="Submit" />
                </p>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div id="div2">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the Submit.php file

```
$idno = ($_POST['idno']);
$gen='';
$img='';

if($idno>=12345){
    $gen="ABC";
    $img="<img src= 'abc.jpg'>";
}else{
    $gen="DEF";
    $img="<img src= 'def.jpg'>";
}

echo "$img";
echo "$gen";
```

This is the Submit.js file

```
function SubmitFormData() {
    var idno = $("#idno").val();
    $.post("submit.php", { idno: idno },
        function(data) {
             $('#div1').html(data);
        });
}
```

**I want to see the $gen value in Div1 and $img value in Div2 when click on the button without refreshing the Index.php page.**

Now, using this Js code, I can see both $gen and $img values in a same div. I tried so many times by changing this js code and submit.php code, but didn't work.

**How can divide that two values into two divs?**

Comment: I suggest to return JSON to be free and unbound of structure: `"{"gen":"ABC","img":"abc.jpg"}"`. Returning structure and/or chains might seem faster now but usually ends up biting you at one point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data that you send and receive to and from the server is send as text. While text itself does not have any meaning, the way it is formatted can.

Introducing JSON. JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation and is a format that can be read by multiple languages. This makes it incredibly useful to exchange information between such platforms. JSON is represented as a string (text) which the language can transform into data that it can use.

Sidenote: although JavaScript is in the name it has nothing to do with it. The structure JSON uses resembles what objects and arrays in JS look like.

PHP for instance has the `json_encode` (data to JSON) and `json_decode` (JSON to data) functions to transform the data.

JavaScript has the `JSON.stringify` (data to JSON) and `JSON.parse` (JSON to data) methods to do the same thing but on its own side.

Let's apply this to your case. So you've got more than 1 value to send to the client. But you can only send once. This calls for the use of an `array()` to send a list of items. In this array put your `$gen` and `$img` values.

Now call `json_encode` to transform your array into JSON and send it to the client.

```php
<?php
$idno = ($_POST['idno']);
$gen = '';
$img = '';

if($idno >= 12345) {
    $gen = "ABC";
    $img = "<img src= 'abc.jpg'>";
} else {
    $gen = "DEF";
    $img = "<img src= 'def.jpg'>";
}

$response = array($gen, $img);
echo json_encode($response);

die();
?>
```

Now on the receiving end. The response that you now get is a string with a JSON structure. Convert this string to usable data with `JSON.parse`.

At this point you have received an array with two values in it. You can loop over the array or manually select something from it to output in your document.

```js
function SubmitFormData() {
    var idno = $("#idno").val();
    $.post("submit.php", { idno: idno },
        function(response) {
             var data = JSON.parse(response);

             // data is now an array with two items.
             var gen = data[0];
             var img = data[1];
 
             $('#div1').html(img);
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some things to make it cleaner but i will go for the least invasive method:

in Submit.php

```php
...
echo $img . ";" . $gen;
```

in Submit.js

```js
function(data) {
  var responseArray = data.split(";");
  $('#div1').html(responseArray[0]);
  $('#div2').html(responseArray[1]);
});
```